# Force10 s25 switch has a memory leak that I can't solve

Tags: memory-leaks, routes

I have two buildings in my school district that are linked by 2 Force10 S25 24-port switches over a 10 Gbps dark fiber connection.  One switch is in building "L" and the other is in building "S".  Building L also hosts the internet connection for the district.  The switch in Building L is on the subnet 10.2.0.0 /16. Building S is on the subnet 10.4.0.0 /16.  The switches strictly serve the purpose of layer 3 routing between buildings and the switch in Building L points at the district's default gateway.  They have very simple configurations with static routes for even more simplicity.  Communication between buildings is fine, but the switch in Building L runs out of memory every 3 hours or so and needs to be rebooted.  This is obviously detrimental to the school day and general productivity.  When I issue the command show process memory, the process tFib4 gradually climbs in its memory usage and seems to be the cause of the problem.  The building "S" switch never fails or has this problem.  I have listed the configurations of each below.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated, as I NEED to get this fixed asap.

configuration for Building "L":

```
Current Configuration ...
! Version 8.4.2.7
! Last configuration change at Tue Sep 23 13:56:13 1997 by default
! Startup-config last updated at Tue Sep 23 13:57:11 1997 by default
!
redundancy auto-synchronize full
!
hardware watchdog
!
hostname HighSchool
!
enable password 
!
username admin secret 
!
stack-unit 0 provision S25N
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/1
  no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/2
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/3
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/4
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/5
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/6
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/7
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/8
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/9
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/10
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/11
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/12
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/13
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/14
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/15
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/16
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/17
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/18
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/19
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/20
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/21
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/22
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/23
 no ip address
 mtu 9216
 switchport
 flowcontrol rx on tx on
 no shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/24
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet 0/27
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet 0/28
 ip address 192.168.1.1/30
 no shutdown
!
interface Vlan 1
!
interface Vlan 200
 ip address 10.2.0.101/16
 untagged GigabitEthernet 0/1-24
 no shutdown
!
ip route 0.0.0.0/0 10.2.0.1
ip route 10.4.0.0/16 TenGigabitEthernet 0/28
!
ip igmp snooping enable
!
buffer-profile global 1Q
!
protocol lldp
 advertise management-tlv system-description system-name
 no disable
 advertise interface-port-desc
!
line console 0
line vty 0
line vty 1
line vty 2
line vty 3
line vty 4
line vty 5
line vty 6
line vty 7
line vty 8
line vty 9
!
end
```

configuration for building "S":

```
Current Configuration ...
! Version 8.4.2.6
! Last configuration change at Mon Sep 22 13:07:28 1997 by admin
! Startup-config last updated at Mon Sep 22 13:07:55 1997 by admin
!
redundancy auto-synchronize full
!
hardware watchdog
!
hostname MiddleSchool
!
enable password 
!
username admin secret 
!
stack-unit 0 provision S25N
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/1
 no ip address
 switchport
 no shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/2
 no ip address
 switchport
 no shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/3
 no ip address
 switchport
 no shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/4
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/5
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/6
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/7
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/8
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/9
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/10
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/11
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/12
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/13
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/14
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/15
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/16
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/17
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/18
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/19
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/20
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/21
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/22
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/23
 no ip address
 mtu 9216
 switchport
 flowcontrol rx on tx on
 no shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/24
 no ip address
 switchport
 shutdown
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet 0/27
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet 0/28
 ip address 192.168.1.2/30
 no shutdown
!
interface Vlan 1
!
interface Vlan 400
 ip address 10.4.0.101/16
 untagged GigabitEthernet 0/1-24
 no shutdown
!
ip route 10.2.0.0/16 TenGigabitEthernet 0/28
!
clock timezone CST -6 0
!
ip igmp snooping enable
!
buffer-profile global 1Q
!
protocol lldp
 advertise management-tlv system-description system-name
 no disable
 advertise interface-port-desc
!
line console 0
line vty 0
line vty 1
line vty 2
line vty 3
line vty 4
line vty 5
line vty 6
line vty 7
line vty 8
line vty 9
!
end
```

Building "L" is one firmware version higher because it was supposed to fix the leak and an internal telnet issue but didn't, so I have not upgraded the building "S" firmware and will be downgrading the building "L" firmware.

Comment: The issue is still unsolved.  I have put together a rough network diagram for a visual if anyone can help.

http://imgur.com/FNbCiK3

Comment: This, children, is why you do **not** route to an interface. If you have an address, Use. It.  For the record, this [`ip route 10.4.0.0/16 TenGigabitEthernet 0/28`] is the problem. (see also: proxy-arp)

Comment: I cross posted it into network engineering yesterday when I found out that the arp table was filling insanely fast.  Mike Pennington diagnosed it as you did, Ricky, and the issue was exactly that.  I now understand to route to the IP and not the interface, but can you explain why routing to the interface causes this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_ARP You're basically telling the host/router/switch the host to which you wish to communicate is "on this link". How do you find a host (L3) on ethernet (L2)? ARP.

Comment: Oh ok, I see.  Using an interface makes it layer 2 because of the MAC, but using the routed IP makes it layer 3.